# Roku API getting the response Method Not Allowed

Tags: roku

Whenever I am hitting any Roku API I am getting an response as Method not allowed

> https://apipub.roku.com/listen/transaction-service.svc/validate-transaction/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Is there something which I am missing here.

[Ref: [Click here]](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Web+Service+API#WebServiceAPI-ValidateTransaction)

I am very new to Roku World can any body help me. Thanks

Comment: How are you making the call? It sounds like you are making a POST request and this should be a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet worked with the Web Service API, but is it possible that you need to call it something like this?

```
Function GetApiArray()
    url = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
    url.SetUrl("http://api.url...")
    rsp = url.GetToString()

    responseXML = ParseXML(rsp)
    responseXML = responseXML.GetChildElements()

    ' Handle the response here

    return result
End Function

Function ParseXML(str As String) As dynamic
    if str = invalid return invalid
    xml=CreateObject("roXMLElement")
    if not xml.Parse(str) return invalid
    return xml
End Function
```

Reference here for urls: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifUrlTransfer#ifUrlTransfer-GetToString()asString